# Discord rewrite and json cant figure out the error

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

I cant figure out whats wrong with the code!
Its supposed to take server name and people and make a database with everybody name under an server.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("setup"):
        try:
            with open("users.json") as json_file:
                data = json.load(json_file)
                for m in data[message.guild]:
                    await ctx.send("Setup has done already!")
        except:
            from os.path import isfile

            if isfile('users.json'):  # check if file exists
                with open('users.json', 'r') as infile:
                    data = json.load(infile)
                    guildset = str(message.guild)
                    data[guildset] = []  # load from existing
                    with open("users.json", "w") as outfile:
                        json.dump(data, outfile)
                        with open("users.json") as json_file:
                            data = json.load(json_file)
                            guild = message.guild
                            for members1 in guild.members:
                                guild = message.guild
                                guildset = str(guild)
                                for m in data[guildset]:
                                    members2 = str(members1)
                                    m[members2].append({
                                        "money": 0,
                                        "count": 0,
                                        "other": 0
                                    })
                                    with open("users.json", "w") as outfile:
                                        json.dump(data, outfile)
```

```
C:\Users\xzyte\Desktop\ZTZ> cmd /C "set "DEBUGPY_LAUNCHER_PORT=51998" && C:\Users\xzyte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe c:\Users\xzyte\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.4.76186\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\no_wheels\debugpy\launcher c:\Users\xzyte\Desktop\ZTZ\main.py "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xzyte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\xzyte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\xzyte\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.4.76186\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\no_wheels\debugpy\__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\xzyte\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.4.76186\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\no_wheels\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\xzyte\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.4.76186\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\no_wheels\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 267, in run_file        
    runpy.run_path(options.target, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
  File "C:\Users\xzyte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 262, in run_path
    code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)
  File "C:\Users\xzyte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 237, in _get_code_from_file
    code = compile(f.read(), fname, 'exec')
  File "c:\Users\xzyte\Desktop\ZTZ\main.py", line 58
    else:  # no file, start from scratch
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

```
C:\Users\xzyte\Desktop\ZTZ> cmd /C "set "DEBUGPY_LAUNCHER_PORT=52010" && C:\Users\xzyte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe c:\Users\xzyte\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.4.76186\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\no_wheels\debugpy\launcher c:\Users\xzyte\Desktop\ZTZ\main.py "
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xzyte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\xzyte\Desktop\ZTZ\main.py", line 42, in on_message
    data = json.load(json_file)
  File "C:\Users\xzyte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Users\xzyte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\xzyte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\xzyte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

```
C:\Users\xzyte\Desktop\ZTZ> cmd /C "set "DEBUGPY_LAUNCHER_PORT=52040" && C:\Users\xzyte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe c:\Users\xzyte\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.4.76186\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\no_wheels\debugpy\launcher c:\Users\xzyte\Desktop\ZTZ\main.py "
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xzyte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\xzyte\Desktop\ZTZ\main.py", line 42, in on_message
    data = json.load(json_file)
  File "C:\Users\xzyte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Users\xzyte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\xzyte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\xzyte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: So what's wrong with it? What error have you got?

Comment: raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: i will add the error to the code

Comment: Because your try except will not work with  `JSONDecodeError` meaning that if the JSON file is empty it will not get passed to the exception and only raise an error. I don't even want to try to fix your code, it is a big mess.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your empty JSON file:

```
{}
```